# Route53 - Subdomain not resolving after adding an A record pointing to a different IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-lightsail

I have a main web app on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk and all the DNS records are already set correctly. But I need a subdomain to redirect to a different IP address (to my lightsail instance).

So I added a new A record in the same hosted zone like so:
[image]

However, when I visit `ctgze.domain.com`, the site won't load. However, if I access the IP address directly, it loads fine (shows the default Apache `index.html` since I have my virtualhost for my app configured for `ctgze.domain.com`.
I have configured apache like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ctgze.domain.com
        ServerAdmin root@localhost
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/domain/domain.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/domain/domain/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/domain/domain/static
        <Directory /var/www/domain/domain/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Make it a CNAME instead of A record.

Comment: I've already tried that, but still doesn't work. Also I've read that CNAME records should point to a URL and not an IP address, if I understood correctly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528652/how-to-set-ip-address-as-cname-record-for-subdomain

Answer (score 2):

It was a browser cache issue.

I tried to access my subdomain using `curl` and it loaded. But in Chrome it times out.
I tried clearing my cache/loading in incognito and it worked.